# How to disable automatic ModelState Validation for a specific Controller / Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As the title mentioned, i want to disable automatic ModelState Validation for a specific Controller / Action.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible. Create custom ModelValidatorProvider.

```
public class CustomModelValidatorProvider 
             : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(
        ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ControllerContext context, 
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidator>();
    }
}
```

and set this provider at startup.

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomModelValidatorProvider());
```

How about this?

Comment: That's one way, right. But if i do it that way i lose it everywhere. Right ? I have done it with a custom ModelBinder, so i can decide where it works.

Comment: Do I need to add that dummy validator to get rid of the default `ModelState` validation? I want to speed up actions in a controller that is not form based, so I don't need the `ModelState` at all for that controller, and thought about conserving performance by dumping it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider clearing the `Modelstate` dictionary in the controller action instead by calling:

```
Modelstate.Clear();
```